# How to grep for the dollar symbol ($)?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

```
% cat temp
$$$ hello1
$$  hello2
    hello3
##  hello4
    hello5 $$$
% cat temp | grep "$$$"
Illegal variable name.
% cat temp | grep "\$\$\$"
Variable name must contain alphanumeric characters.
%
```

I want to grep for `$$$` and I expect the result to be

```
% cat temp | grep <what should go here?>
$$$ hello1
    hello5 $$$
%
```

To differentiate, I have marked the prompt as `%`.

- What is the problem here?
- What should the **grep string** be?

Comment: Your second command is correct (with $ escaped), but you need to use single quotes, not double quotes.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The problem is that the shell expands variable names inside double-quoted strings. So for `"$$$"` it tries to read a variable name starting with the first `$`.

In single quotes, on the other hand, variables are not expanded. Therefore, `'$$$'` *would* work – if it were not for the fact that `$` is a special character in regular expressions denoting the line ending. So it needs to be escaped: `'\$\$\$'`.

Answer (score 25):

When you use double quotes `"` or none use double`\: "\\\$\\\$\\\$"`

```
cat t | grep \\\$\\\$\\\$
```

if you use in single quotes ' you may use:

```
cat t | grep '\$\$\$'
```

Comment: You could use -F to avoid adding escape chars. So `grep -F '$$$'`

Comment: (extending on previous comment): as in: echo '$hello' | grep -F '$hello'

Answer (score 8):

```
$ grep '\$\$\$' temp
$$$ hello1
hello5 $$$
```

There's a superflous 'cat' in your command.

Answer (score 5):

Works for me:

```
user@host:~$ cat temp | grep '\$\$\$'
$$$ hello1
hello5 $$$
user@host:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `^.*[$]{3}.*$`