# Searching file containing dollar sign $ with grep

Tags: regex, grep

How do I search a file containing `$`using grep?

I've tried

`grep "\$" file.txt`

and it does not recognize the `$` character to search for.

Comment: Maybe `grep "\\\$" file.txt`? Just escape until you get a match. :)

Comment: `grep "\\\$" file.txt`  and `grep \\$ file.txt` and `grep '\$' file.txt` all work, but ojblass's comment is the most insightful.

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3759978/66519) in another stack exchange forum.  Basically you should try grep '\$'.

Answer (score 2):

As I posted in my comment,

```
grep "\\\$" file.txt
```

The first `\\` is a literal `\` for the regex engine, and the thrid `\` is used to escape the dollar symbol.

A rule of thumb with matching a *literal* dollar symbol is:

1. Escape up to 3 times
2. Try doubling `$` (i.e. `$$`)

Some of it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `grep \\$ file.txt` works