# How to delete all lines starting with $

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I have a file, and I want to delete all the lines starting with `$` in it.

Sample.txt

```
$ This is a test
$ All the lines starting with $ must be deleted
Data1
Data2
Data3
```

I used the `grep` command and it didn't work for some reason

```
grep -v '^$' Sample.txt > Output.txt
```

Desired Output is shown below.

Output.txt

```
Data1
Data2
Data3
```

Comment: Escape "$" with "\".

Comment: @Cyrus you mean '^\$'? why does $ need escape character?

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: `sed '/^\$/d' file > newfile`, [demo](https://ideone.com/cwegrB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the dollar sign. Inside double quotes, `$` is interpreted as the beginning of a variable name. Inside single quotes, `$` is a special character in regular expressions denoting the line ending. So do this instead:

```
grep -v '^\$' Sample.txt > Output.txt
```

Also check [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759926/how-to-grep-for-the-dollar-symbol) on SO.